# Android: How can I show my long message on a toast for android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, toast

my toast message is also a bit long for android wear. It isn't seem good or professional.

How can I fix that problem?

Thanks

Comment: Make the message shorter?

Comment: sorry but I have to show standard message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to split the message into two lines like:

```
 Toast.makeText("bla bla ....../r/n  ....bla bla",null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This can be help for your problem.